# ZK datebox can't change hour value

Tags: java, zk

This's my datebox

```
<datebox value="@bind(vm.myDate)" format="d/M/yyyy hh:mm"/>
```

I can change day, month, year and minutes, accepted hour. it default to current hour, when I change to other hour it reset to that value.

on my vm myDate is type of java.util.Date

```
Date myDate;
public Date getMyDate(){
    return myDate;
}
public void setMyDate(Date myDate){
    this.myDate = myDate;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ZK cannot decide whether you are meaning AM or PM on input. And therefore - my interpretation - it does nothing.

You can either add an AM/PM input element like

```
 format="d/M/yyyy a hh:mm"
```

or you can set the 24h format:

```
format="d/M/yyyy HH:mm"
```

Comment: Thank @flo it help me a lot.